# MySQL Stored Procedure Setting Variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedures in MySQL

I wonder if for example I have a query then I divide it into variables like

```
SELECT A, B, C, FROM TABLE123 WHERE A = '123'
```

Then I divide it into variables inside the stored procedure

```
SET @select = 'SELECT';
SET @column1= 'A';
SET @column2 = 'B';
SET @column3 = 'C';
SET @parameter = 'WHERE';
SET @equal = '=';
```

Then from there I can use each part or the query or variable in a conditional statement depending on the parameter set when calling the stored procedure.

I wonder if this is allowed as standard practice or will it cause any performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is similar to [Dynamic SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Here is a basic **how-to** base from MySQL Docs:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
SET @a = 3;
SET @b = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

+------------+
| hypotenuse |
+------------+
|          5 |
+------------+
```

Here's a great article written by an SQL Server MVP about [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), which you might want to read. Although this is for sql server, there might be some similar information for mysql.